# removing sprites of lost reference from page in cocos 2d

Tags: sprite

I am using a single sprite again and again (requirement of program) for different animations on different touch location and keeping the final image after each animation on screen ***[sprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName***:@"abc.png"] .
Now problem is that after completion of all animation i want to remove all done animation's final image from screen but due to using same sprite again and again sprite has only reference  of last done animation and using ***[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:true]*** only remove last done animation.Please help me to remove all done animation spriteFrame.

here is sample code

-(void)draw1
{
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"a.plist"];

```
// Create a sprite sheet with the  images
spritebatch= [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"a.png"];
[self addChild:sprite z:12];
// Load up the frames of our animation

NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 13; ++i) {
    [animFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"crta%d.png", i]]];

}
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:.1f];

sprite=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"crta13.png"];

[self addChild:sprite z:20];
drawaction = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim] times:1];
 //[CCRepeat actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation] times:1];
[sprite runAction:drawaction];
```

}
-(void)draw2
{
  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"a.plist"];

```
// Create a sprite sheet with the  images
spritebatch= [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"a.png"];
[self addChild:sprite z:12];
// Load up the frames of our animation

NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 13; ++i) {
    [animFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"crta%d.png", i]]];

}
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:.1f];

sprite=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"crta13.png"];

[self addChild:sprite z:20];
drawaction = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim] times:1];
 //[CCRepeat actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation] times:1];
[sprite runAction:drawaction];


}
```